# Java getting letter of Local Disk Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, filesystems, jfilechooser

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class DriveLetter{
static String getDriveLetter(){

    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();   
    File[] f = File.listRoots();
    String letter = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
        if((fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]).contains("Disk") || fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]).contains("Local")) &&
                fsv.isDrive(f[i]) && !fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]) && f[i].canRead() &&
                f[i].canWrite() && f[i].getUsableSpace() > 10000000){

            letter = f[i].toString().charAt(0) + ":";
            break;
        }
    } 
    return letter; 
    }
}

public class Main{
public static void main(String args []){
    if(DriveLetter.getDriveLetter() != null){
        new File(DriveLetter.getDriveLetter() + "\\aaa\\bbb").mkdirs();
    }

    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, DriveLetter.getDriveLetter(),
                "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

I wrote a method to get local disk letter. It works fine on my laptop.
However it doesn't work on my secondary computer, I get null error as if computer had no primary disk. I gave the code to my friend to test it out and it worked for him, but then I tried it on my brothers computer it did not work again.

It seems like my code to get letter of primary disk is very unreliable. Maybe someone could give me some suggestions to make it more reliable?

Also I was looking for an easy way to get primary disk letter on windows using java, but I couldn't find anything useful...

Maybe someone knows an easier way to get letter of primary disk?

Comment: Post the stacktrace, please.

Comment: There is no stacktrace.
What I mean by null error is the getDriveLetter() returns null, since none of drives met if condition, however it does work on most windows computer.
But I'm not sure what I need to tweak to make it work for everyone using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.listRoots() is doing exactly what you need it to do. I'm not sure what you need the rest of the code for, but that will return all used drive letters on your system.

Is this code specifically for local disks? i.e. must it exclude USB drives and SAN attached volumes?

Also, a few points:

- Both of your checks that the system display name of the drive contains "disk" or "local" will fail if the user has renamed a partition. For example, my C: drive is called "OS", that call fails and thus the method returns null
- Your method will also return null if there is less than 9.5 MB free on the drive (why is this a condition?)
- Your method will also return null if the java process does not have permission to read AND write to that drive, which it may not do if run under UAC or other userspace restrictions

Comment: My goal is to create some folders on local disk. There I could save information about my program, which I don't want to store on main .jar file. However if I do something like "C:\\aaa\\bbb").mkdirs(); and C disk does not exist I'm screwed, so I need to detect Local disk letter.

edit: I removed name checks, did not know you could rename it. Will give a test run tomorrow hopefully it will work better.

Other conditions need to be met if I want to store information on that disk.